# Are there any limitation on crypto day trading?

Tags: robinhood

I'm trading crypto on Robinhood. My account is over $30,000 (for the last month). But today I got this weird message:

> Because you are marked as a pattern day trader, your account will be restricted from placing day trades if you purchase 1 BTC.

Why? I tried contacting their customer support, but still didn't get an answer. Is there any additional limitations? I have never had this issue trading stock there. Is this a bug?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Read: [Pattern Day Trading](https://robinhood.com/us/en/support/articles/pattern-day-trading/) and [Account Limitations](https://robinhood.com/us/en/support/articles/account-limitations/)

Comment: Did you follow that "Learn More" link?